# How to skip some response messages based on a pattern while generating html reports from JTL

Tags: html, exception, command-line, jmeter, report

In my tests, often requests return a very long response message which is dozens of lines long. My tests involve high load so these messages occurs thousands of times. In the end the JTL becomes huge and due to these large response messages, I am getting out of heap memory and array size too large exceptions when I try to generate HTML reports from command line. Test machines have some 16 GB and JTL are around 5 GB only. I allocated max heap of up to 15 GB but issue persists.

As a workaround I need to make jmeter skip considering these response messages alone while generating HTML report. But I still need the particular line item to be part of the report because it is part of the over all load. That is, I cannot skip these resposes entirely.

Any way to do this? Please let me know if any additional details are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to remove the part of the response message which is not interesting.

Example code which removes the response message part after first dot:

```
prev.setResponseMessage(prev.getResponseMessage().split('\\.')[0])
```

In the above code `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for use from JSR223 Test Elements

Demo:

[image]